# Adding an extra statement to existing SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to modify an SQL statement that returns the number of Incidents logged by a user. The current statement is -

```
SELECT 
    USERS.NAME, 
    Count(INCIDENTS_H.SERVICEREQNO) 
FROM Sostenuto.sunrise.INCIDENTS_H INCIDENTS_H 
INNER JOIN  Sostenuto.sunrise.USERS USERS 
    ON INCIDENTS_H.OWNERACCOUNT = USERS.SERVICEREQNO 
WHERE (INCIDENTS_H.ADDEDDATE >= {ts '2013-11-25 00:00:00'}) 
    AND (INCIDENTS_H.OPERATIONID = 102005166) 
    AND (INCIDENTS_H.OWNERGROUP = 123000012 
        OR INCIDENTS_H.OWNERGROUP=123000031 
        OR INCIDENTS_H.OWNERGROUP=123000047) 
    AND (INCIDENTS_H.ADDEDBY=INCIDENTS_H.OWNERACCOUNT) 
GROUP BY USERS.NAME
```

Which works fine. Howeever I need to add another clause into the statement from a different table, I need to also include-

```
INCIDENTS.ADDEDBY = INCIDENTS_H.OWNERACCOUNT
```

However I am struggling to modify the original statement to include this. Can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Please tag your dbms.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    USERS.NAME, 
    Count(INCIDENTS_H.SERVICEREQNO) 
FROM Sostenuto.sunrise.INCIDENTS_H INCIDENTS_H 
INNER JOIN  Sostenuto.sunrise.USERS USERS 
    ON INCIDENTS_H.OWNERACCOUNT = USERS.SERVICEREQNO
INNER JOIN INCIDENTS I
    ON INCIDENTS.ADDEDBY = INCIDENTS_H.OWNERACCOUNT
WHERE (INCIDENTS_H.ADDEDDATE >= {ts '2013-11-25 00:00:00'}) 
    AND (INCIDENTS_H.OPERATIONID = 102005166) 
    AND (INCIDENTS_H.OWNERGROUP = 123000012 
        OR INCIDENTS_H.OWNERGROUP=123000031 
        OR INCIDENTS_H.OWNERGROUP=123000047) 
    AND (INCIDENTS_H.ADDEDBY=INCIDENTS_H.OWNERACCOUNT) 
GROUP BY USERS.NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried your suggestion, but it does not seem to be correctly picking up the Where section now. So initially I had count results in the single or double digits, they are now anywhere from 3 - 5 digits long. Any idea?

Comment: What you're looking for is help with basic sql join. I think it may help to read up on different joins.... I can help you but I don't know if I can explain it better than here... http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp also look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Ping me again if you need additional help.

Comment: My guess would be that not all INCIDENTS_H records have a corresponding INCIDENTS value. Or that they are one to one mapping.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT u.NAME, Count(h.SERVICEREQNO) 
FROM Sostenuto.sunrise.INCIDENTS_H h 
    Join Sostenuto.sunrise.USERS u  
       ON h.OWNERACCOUNT = u.SERVICEREQNO 
    Join Incidents i 
       On i.ADDEDBY = h.OWNERACCOUNT 
WHERE (h.ADDEDDATE>={ts '2013-11-25 00:00:00'}) 
AND (h.OPERATIONID=102005166) 
AND (h.OWNERGROUP=123000012 OR h.OWNERGROUP=123000031 OR h.OWNERGROUP=123000047) 
AND (h.ADDEDBY=h.OWNERACCOUNT) 
GROUP BY u.NAME
```

Comment: As per the update to Sam Yi's answer. Any additional help much appreciated.